# Trying to make a clickable navigation bar which can be clicked to close

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically im trying to make it so in the navigation bar below, the black bar that pops up on right once open button is clicked can be closed by clicking anywhere on the black bar itself, instead of using the x button on top right. Is this something that is possible? The code can be found below

```js
function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
```

```css
         body {
           font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
         }
    
         .sidenav {
          height: 100%;
          width: 0;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 1;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          background-color: #111;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          transition: 0.5s;
          padding-top: 60px;
          }
    
    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you do.  Though usually clicking anywhere in the page (not the black sidebar) close the black sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```js
window.addEventListener("load",onLoadHandler);
function onLoadHandler(e){
  let side = document.getElementById("mySidenav",closeNav);
  side.addEventListener("click",closeNav)
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
     body {
       font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
     }

     .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
      }

    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Right-sided Navigation</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the right-sided navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Have a nice day.
Nicolas.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I know this wasnt in the original question but what would i have to do in the onload function to  make the blackbar clickable for both opening and closing. if i were to bring the black bar out a bit

Comment: @D.Mann just let another div clickable and call openNav()
I cannot make a snippet in a comment... :(